# ORACLE SQL Query IN CLAUSE or other solution

Tags: sql, oracle, in-clause

I have a existing big query that has a subquery deep in the trenches that gets an employee based on a ID.

```
SELECT BIG QUERY.....................................
 ( Select mananger_id from Employee_table where employee_id=123)
)
```

now I have a newer requirement to address multiple employee Ids. max number of employees in a group is 200

```
 SELECT BIG QUERY.....................................
     ( Select mananger_id from Employee_table where employee_id IN (?,?,?... 200X?))
    )
```

1. Is this the best method? If not what should I do. What the best option
2. Would there be any performance implications on the IN clause

Comment: If you are certain that there can't be more than 200 employees in a group, then this method should be fine both from code and performance perspectives. If there can be more than 1000 then you have a problem with Oracle's "IN" limit.
It is not clear, whether this query is called from some application or from anywhere else but in your place I'd suggest to split this query into smaller bits for better maintainability, cleanliness and even performance - probably along the way you'll find a way how to make it run faster.

Comment: In general, when a semi-join (an IN condition) makes sense logically, it is the most efficient way to get the desired result. Other than that, to show how to select from a list of 200 employees, you must tell us how you are going to give the **input** list to a query. A common, but inefficient, way is as a string. It can be handled, but it's messy. (It is very easy on the "client end" though, which is why many people insist on using it.) Much better: numbers saved in a table, or coming from a view, or coming in as a nested table (collection object).

Comment: The Employee ID is coming from an external system. For now, the max limit is 200. what are my options to make it scalable. What would be the best solution to accommodate sat more than 1000.  It cannot be put into another permanent table. All criteria to the big query(including small) is passed as parametrized

Comment: Why "it can not be put into another permanent table"?

Comment: @Littlefoot - The Employee ID is coming from an external system. For now, the max limit is 200. what are my options to make it scalable. What would be the best solution to accommodate sat more than 1000. It cannot be put into another permanent table. All criteria to the big query(including small) is passed as parametrized

Answer (score 0):

How exactly are you using this sub query?

For example if you code actually looks like this:

```
SELECT BIG QUERY.....................................
FROM table
WHERE table.manager_id = 
 ( Select mananger_id from Employee_table where employee_id=123)
)
```

Then it is better to do this:

```
SELECT BIG QUERY.....................................
FROM table
JOIN Employee_table E on e.employee_id = 123 AND table.manager_id = e.manager_ID
```

Since you don't give much details how you get the 200 entries I can't add more detail but you can see how doing a join might be extended depending on your use

Comment: The Employee ID is coming from an external system. For now, the max limit is 200. what are my options to make it scalable. What would be the best solution to accommodate sat more than 1000.  It cannot be put into another permanent table. All criteria to the big query(including small) is passed as parametrized

Comment: @Marco as a string?

Comment: In a web Service as a list

Comment: @Marco-- I don't think there is type "list" as a parameter.  Am I miss-understanding you?

Comment: as a repeatable element? maxOccurs="unbounded"

Comment: @Marco I'm asking about the type of the parameter -- you are talking about the contents

Comment: Sorry I misunderstood. Yes, Employee ID is a String. It currently comes as one String. Now they will send as a list of 200 strings. I need to incorporate that in the IN clause.

Comment: a list of 200 strings is not a data type.  how are they sending the list.  are they sending it as a table parameter?  if so you can just join to it.

Comment: I should give more info. As explained above, the data/criteria is coming in thru a web service. Its a list in the web service. All the contents/criteria is then plugged into a parameterized prepared Statement and queried using JDBC. So it cannot be joined.(based on my understanding)

Comment: @marco   Here is an article about passing a table as a parameter -- do this with one column and then inner join to this table. https://technology.amis.nl/it/oracle-jdbc-passing-a-table-of-custom-object-type-to-a-stored-procedure-implementing-efficient-single-round-trip-data-exchange-part-two-of-an-adf-application-on-a-plsql-api/